# How to create a fractal spiral in python with turtle?

Tags: python, math

I'm trying to create a python program that draws a fractal spiral with user input.

I have looked at other questions very similar to mine but it doesn't quite give me what I would like, and I keep getting error messages.

This is what I have tried:

```py
a = int(input("Size? "))
b = int(input("Angle? "))
c = int(input("How many times do you want to repeat? "))

from turtle import *

def fractalSpiral(size, angle, amount):
  for i in range(amount):
    forward(size)
    left(angle)
    forward(size + 50)
    left(angle + 10)

fractalSpiral(a, b, c)
```

Witch the inputs `a = 50`, `b = 60`, and `c = 9`, I get the shape in the attachment, which does **not** look like a fractal spiral.

Can I have some help please?[image]

[image]

Comment: @Rory Daulton I thought I added it?

Comment: Nevermind added it now, sorry

Comment: What does a fractal spiral look like? I'm not sure whether it's possible for a turtle to mimic say a Mandelbrot plot, because that's a map of a complex-plane, while a turtle follows simple vectors. It'd be interesting to find a fractal vector-based analogue to something like that - but the closest I can think of would be to use (an approximation of a) transcendental number like phi for your orientation calculations.

Comment: A fractal is a recurring geometric pattern that is repeated at ever smaller scales to produce irregular shapes. This is what the internet says. I thought it would be possible to create, maybe not exactly like that super complex one but a spiral that would be classified as, "fractal".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see in the second picture, you want a shape that is constructed of triangles where every triangle is a little bigger than the previous one and also set to a little different angle. I thought I would go with an Egyptian 3:4:5 triangle and came up with this:

```
def spiral(step, angle, max):                                                                                           
    for i in range(0, max, step):                                                                                       
        turtle.forward(i*3)                                                                                             
        turtle.left(126.87)                                                                                             
        turtle.forward(i*5)                                                                                             
        turtle.left(143.2)                                                                                              
        turtle.forward(i*4)                                                                                             
        turtle.left(90 + angle)
```

You can now play with the parameters to get a result that would please you. If you want a different triangle, you would need to recalculate its angles using trigonometry. Remember that to get angle alpha, you need to turn you turtle 180 - alpha.

Comment: Cool! Zefciu, would you mind using hashtags to explain a little for me? I'm not sure I quite get the code, however, your code produces pretty much what I want! Thanks. So just - explanations? And the math too, I'm not the brightest kid.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I will leave you here. I have given you a working example and also pointed to the math field that you should use. It is up to you to take on from here.

Comment: At least tell me why the left turns have to be 126.87 and 143.2?

Comment: The angles in the right triangle can be calculated with arcsin function of the ratios of its sides:
```180 - math.degrees(math.asin(3/5)) == 143.13010235415598``` while 
```180 - math.degrees(math.asin(4/5)) == 126.86989764584402```